# Sorting with condition in based on negative and positive value in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to sort based on below condition where I have hidden one numeric value with '-' i want to sort in a manner that however I sort (desc,asc) '-' should come on top or at the bottom but it does not affect my sorting, below goes an example 
and - can be a negative or positive value

```
before sorting  
1
2
3
-
5
6
7

after sorting 
-
1
2
3
5
6
7
```

Comment: `'-'` is not a numeric value, so I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the sort order expression to be something like

```
=Val(Fields!myColumn.Value)
```

This will return zero for the `-` row and the numeric value for the other rows.

If this does not help, edit the question (rather than add more comments) and show what the data looks like that comes from your dataset query in the report.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite unclear what the data type of the column is, because `-` is not a numeric value.

However, regardless of the type, this does what you want:

```
order by col
```

If the column is a number and `-` is `NULL`, this works because an ascending sort puts `NULL` values first.

If the column is a string and `'-'` is the value, this works because `'-'` sorts before numbers.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=772e0f3a5ac6ca2d0f99f26b0dc30ef4) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Sort using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN col = '-' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    col;
```

Actually, it appears that you are mixing character and numeric data in the same column.  In order to bear the value `-`, it must be text, so we should probably do a bit extra work to make sure the text numbers sort properly:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN col = '-' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(10), col);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need in ssrs expression